# Get Spotlight to search in Caskroom subdirs (which is now in /usr/local/)

Tags: homebrew, spotlight, search, indexing

I'm using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) with [Caskroom](https://caskroom.github.io/) and since a recent update, it installs the apps downloaded through `brew cask` within `/usr/local/Caskroom/`

I always used Spotlight to find and open these apps, but now that they're within /usr/local/, Spotlight doesn't seem to find them anymore.

I've checked Spotlight's preferences but there is no folder excluded, nor is there anything else disabled that could cause this.

Is there a way to tell Spotlight to search within `/usr/local/Caskroom/`?

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer provided by user vitorgalvao on the project's Github page: https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/issues/22317

> Spotlight doesn’t index /usr/local/, that why we started using /opt in the first place. Reinstall your apps with --force and they’ll be moved (our new behaviour). Spotlight will see them then.

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding the spotlight index on your mac:

1. Choose Apple  menu > System Preferences, then click Spotlight.
2. Click the Privacy tab.
3. Drag the folder or disk that you want to index again to the list of locations that Spotlight is prevented from searching. Click OK to confirm.
4. Select the folder or disk you just added, then click the Remove (–) button to remove it from the list.
5. Quit System Preferences. Spotlight will reindex the contents of the folder or disk.

From [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201716) website.

Comment: Thanks, but no, unfortunately that didn't help. I added the Caskroom folder, closed settings, went back and removed it, and closed again. But even several hours later, Spotlight still doesn't find anything in that Caskroom folder. I also checked if non-accessibility could be causing this, but the user rights on Caskroom and its subdirs are readable for user, group, and others.